# UIView stops at object Storyboard position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I am attempting to use a `UIView` animation to move a label. In my view in the Storyboard, the object is positioned at (257, 375, 87, 21). In my `viewDidLoad` method, I use the following lines of code:

```
textLabel.alpha = 0;
textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(257, 500, 87, 21);
[textLabel removeConstraints:textLabel.constraints];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(257, 50, 87, 21);
textLabel.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The animation starts the label at (257, 50, 87, 21), but it stops moving at y value 375 rather than 50. How do I make the label move all the way to the final frame rather than stopping at its position in interface builder?

Comment: Block based animations have been the recommendation for many years now. Begin Commit is really old.

Comment: Have you tried using this code in `viewDidAppear:`?

Comment: pasta12 is right.  viewDidAppear: is a more appropriate place for starting your animations.  The view isn't guaranteed to be displayed/finished loading at the time your code is run in viewDidLoad.